# H2O import_mojo throws error on the path while loading model from DBFS

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, h2o, automl

I am trying to load the saved model using this path from dbfs file store from my databricks notebook

```
h2o.import_mojo("dbfs:/dbfs/FileStore/df/Churn_Models/h2o_leader_model_train_Cape Town_2020-11-18.model/mojo_model/")
```

it keeps throwing exception whenever I have a space in the path name like in `Cape Town` but it loads when the city name does not have any space in between like `Bahrain`

```
OSError: Job with key $03010a8b400432d4ffffffff$_a0ec664b5212ee40152607d08d30445d failed with an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 64: dbfs:/dbfs/FileStore/df/Churn_Models/h2o_leader_model_train_Cape Town_2020-11-18.model/mojo_model/
```

I have tried encoding the path but didn't work. I have different models for each city which I need to load and run. some have space in it as well. So I want one of the following solutions:

1. Rename all saved folders by removing spaces
2. Deal with the spaces while loading the model.

**Note:**
I am using H2o models in pyspark notebook on databricks

Comment: Can you escape the spaces in the path using "Cape\ Town"?

Comment: @mck it harcodes it like this 
dbfs:/dbfs/FileStore/df/Churn_Models/h2o_leader_model_train_Cape\ Town_2020-11-18.model/mojo_model

Comment: @mck It hardcodes the path and it doesn't escape spaces I have copied the path in the above comment

Comment: @mck It hardcodes the path and it doesn't escape spaces I have copied the path in the above comment

Comment: just modify the code. if you can't modify the code there's nothing that you can do.

Comment: @mck I did modified the code above shared path was the output.. Thanks

Comment: Change this line `h2o.import_mojo("dbfs:/dbfs/FileStore/df/Churn_Models/h2o_leader_model_train_Cape Town_2020-11-18.model/mojo_model/")` to `h2o.import_mojo("dbfs:/dbfs/FileStore/df/Churn_Models/h2o_leader_model_train_Cape\ Town_2020-11-18.model/mojo_model/")`

Comment: @mck Yes I did exactly this and gives me same error OSError: Job with key $03010a8b400532d4ffffffff$_9d2e41e5d9dc4e03ebe29e4f106e4d34 failed with an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 64: dbfs:/dbfs/FileStore/df/Churn_Models/h2o_leader_model_train_Cape\ Town_2020-11-18.model/mojo_model/

Comment: @mck I am running this h2o.import_mojo("dbfs:/dbfs/FileStore/df/Churn_Models/h2o_leader_model_train_Cape\ Town_2020-11-18.model/mojo_model/")

Comment: please modify your question so that others can understand this better

Comment: How about using Python's Raw String, put an `r` in front of the string: `r"dbfs:/dbfs/FileStore/df/Churn_Models/h2o_leader_model_train_Cape Town_2020-11-18.model/mojo_model/"`